# Trouble installing hmatrix through MSYS2 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, haskell, installation, msys2, hmatrix

I've been trying to install hmatrix on my (64-bit) Windows 10 computer; after searching through and trying many possible solutions (including the instructions under "Windows" and "Alternative Windows Build" given [here](https://github.com/albertoruiz/hmatrix/blob/master/INSTALL.md)), I decided to pursue the course of action given on this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3y7ysk/installing_hmatrix_in_windows/cybar0k).

However, when I type in the command

```
cabal install hmatrix -fopenblas --extra-lib-dir=${c:\msys64\mingw64\bin} --extra-include-dir=${c:\msys64\mingw64\include}
```

into the MSYS2 shell, the following log is given:

```
Resolving dependencies... 
Configuring hmatrix-0.17.0.2...
Failed to install hmatrix-0.17.0.2
Build log ( C:\Users\Christian\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\hmatrix-0.17.0.2.log ):
Configuring hmatrix-0.17.0.2...
cabal.exe: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing C library: libopenblas
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
cabal: Leaving directory 'C:\msys64\tmp\cabal-tmp-4244\hmatrix-0.17.0.2'
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
hmatrix-0.17.0.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

However, when I check the directory `c:\msys64\mingw64\bin`, I see that `libopenblas.dll` is right there; I don't know why cabal can't seem to find it.

Any insight into why this is not working or what to do?

**UPDATE:**
The files `libopenblas.dll.a` and `libopenblas.a` are in the directory `c:\msys64\mingw64\lib`. Is it possible I need to somehow include this directory as well? (If I do, how would I do that?)

I also downloaded the files in Alex Vorobiev's comment below and put them in `c:\msys64\mingw64\bin` if they are .dlls or `c:\msys64\mingw64\lib` if they are .libs. The header files were already contained in `c:\msys64\include\openblas`.

I tried several variations on the command in the original post after making these changes, including switching `\bin` with `\lib` and switching `\include` with `\include\openblas`, but all of them still give the same error.

Comment: dll is not enough to be able to compile with the library. You need development files as well - c++ headers and .lib files. See here http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/#libraries_mingw

Comment: I tried downloading files and proceeding as detailed above in my edit, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit suspicious about the

```
 if os(windows)
    if flag(openblas)
        extra-libraries:    libopenblas
```

in the cabal file, could you unpack it and remove the "lib" part? If that doesn't work please post a log with -v3 output. I've seen quite a few people with troubles installing this package. So could you also open a ticket on the GHC bug tracker if this doesn't work (and CC me "Phyx-")?

Secondly, you never said which version of GHC you're using. 8.0.1 should have far less trouble (and won't need the hack to get it working in GHCi) since the runtime linker has been overhauled and should be much better on Windows. 8.0.2 will likely include the new import libraries support as well.